# Does anyone know how to solve GDAL problem with batch translating rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am trying to use the GDAL module in QGIS to convert some NetCDF files into GeoTiff through batch processing. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error even after several attempts. This is the error's text body:

```
    2017-01-06T23:57:04 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetBatchBase.py", line 73, in onRun
            self.batchRun()
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\doTranslate.py", line 306, in batchRun
            self.runItem(self.batchIndex, self.batchTotal)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLA~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetBatchBase.py", line 107, in runItem
            self.base.refreshArgs(args)
        TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

N.B: I've tried this earlier in the day on a different laptop and it worked, therfore the files are not a problem.

Comment: this seems to be a [known issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15626) logged against 2.16. It looks like running it in 2.14 might be a workaround, which might explain why it worked on your other laptop.

Comment: Oh, great. My worries were something has to be done in code, which I don't know. Guess I'll be switching for an older version:)